# Vba loop values not exact

Tags: excel, vba

I don't understand why my simple loop in vba not working as I want.

I would like to make a diagram and loop through the x axis values with a step = 0,01.
I cut out part of the code, probably not necessary for this question.

My problem is that the generated values are not exact. It should be something like: 0; 0,01; 0,02; ... and so on but around 0,82 the cell value is: 0,820000000000001 and after that the error goes on.

This little bit of difference between 0,82 and 0,820000000000001 is not much but makes a lot of problem for me. For example:
in the loop I can not use this:
`If x = 0.82 ...`  because it is not going to be equal. I can cure this problem but there are others and maybe there  is a simpler solution.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Generate_Punch()


Dim NoL As Integer
NoL = Worksheets("Punch").Range("D5").Value 'Number of loops

Dim d As Double
d = Worksheets("Punch").Range("D4").Value 'value of increment/step


'which line start
Dim i As Integer
i = 15

'Coordinate values:
Dim x, y As Double
x = 0
y = 0


Worksheets("Punch").Range("A" & i & ":F32767").Clear

For j = 1 To NoL
    
    'Counter
    Worksheets("Punch").Cells(i, 1).Value = j
    
    'X coordinate values:
    Worksheets("Punch").Cells(i, 2).Value = x

    '.... .... ....
    
    i = i + 1
    x = x + d
Next j

End Sub
```

Thank you for your answers.
Best regards,

Robert

Comment: Quick solution round it like: x = Round(x + d, 2)

Comment: A slightly less quick but much better solution is to increment in integers and then `.Value = Round(x / 100, 2)`.

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/news/beware-of-a-bug-in-excel-when-doing-addition/#:~:text=Office%2Dwatch.com%20details%20a,anomaly%20from%20April%2029%2C%202008.